# WPF DatePicker Defaulting to American Style Date Instead of British

Tags: .net, user-interface, c#-4.0, wpf-controls

I am using a DatePicker in my WPF form, and am having the problem that when a user enters a date in British format, ie 31/12/1980, WPF seems to want to convert it to American, so it reads 12/31/1980.

This is giving me an out of range exception on my SQL insert.

Has anyone come across this before, and if so, how did you fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to make sure that the UI has the correct locale set.

I'm not sure about WPF, but I know that in Silverlight there's a bug whereby the XAML isn't honouring the locale of Windows. You have to include the following code into the constructor of the view:

```
// Get "StringFormat=c" to honour culture settings.
// From http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2010/08/11/stringformat-and-currentculture-in-silverlight.aspx
this.Language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name);
```

Now if your computer isn't set to `en-GB` but your application requires this you'll need to force the language either by setting the `CurrentCulture` of the application thread or passing in "en-GB".

Comment: Hi Chris. Your answer put me on the right track. Thanks for that. However, I discovered that the Language must be explicitly defined in the Window section like so: **Language="en-GB"**, otherwise for some reason, it will default back to American. Strange, but it has done the trick. Thanks for putting me on the right path. Rich

Comment: Looks like Window.Language is default = "en-US" according to the documentation. http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(SYSTEM.WINDOWS.FRAMEWORKELEMENT.LANGUAGE)%3bk(VS.XAMLEDITOR)%3bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22)&rd=true

Answer (score 0):

The ways to implement this (suggestive) approach are:

- Set the culture details in a config file
- Store different (as required) formats for date (maybe w.r.t different country and/or culture) in a standard location like a resource file or config (might as well be in a XML file); and use those saved settings in the start-up/main execution
- Sample code:-

  ```
  System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB");

  cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DateFormat_UK"];

  System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
  ```
- Giving an administrator controlled module could also be considered